# Does OpenStack specify behavior of DELETE in ObjectStore when GET (or download) Object is in progress?

Tags: download, get, openstack

If an object in the object-store is being downloaded, but then a delete command for the object is issued (before the download has completed), what is the expected behavior?

Does delete fail? 
Or, does delete execute after download as completed?